# How to modify this function to merge the values of a key?

Tags: javascript, object, key, concatenation

I'm looking to merge the values of the "year" Key in the object "userName".

I have the following array of objects

```
userName=[{
            loginName:'jimmy',
            deviation:[{dates:[20150222,20150223,20150224,20150225], type:'vacation'}],
            year:'2015'
          },
         {
           loginName:'jimmy',
           deviation:[{dates:[20150322,20150323,20150324,20150325], type:'sick'}],
           year:'2016'
         },
         {
          loginName:'chloe',
          deviation:[{dates:[20150222,20150221,20150224,20150225], type:'national free day'}],
          year:'2016'
         },
        ];
```

and by using this function I am able to sort the deviation dates according to the loginName. So in this case the user 'jimmy' will be shown only once but all devaiation dates and types combined. However the value of the key 'year' inherits only the first value and stays like that. How can I merge the key 'year',  so that for user 'jimmy' year will display '2015, 2016' by modifying my current function:

```
var mergedUsername = [];

    userName.forEach(function(deviation) { 
       var existing = mergedUsername.filter(function(v, i) { 
       return v.loginName == deviation.loginName; 
       }); 
    if(existing.length) {
      var existingIndex = mergedUsername.indexOf(existing[0]);
      mergedUsername[existingIndex].deviation = mergedUsername[existingIndex].deviation.concat(deviation.deviation); 
    }  else {
        if(typeof deviation.deviation == 'string')
        deviation.deviation = [deviation.deviation];
        mergedUsername.push(deviation);  
     }
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` to get desired result.

```js
var data = [{
  loginName: 'jimmy',
  deviation: [{
    dates: [20150222, 20150223, 20150224, 20150225],
    type: 'vacation'
  }],
  year: '2015'
}, {
  loginName: 'jimmy',
  deviation: [{
    dates: [20150322, 20150323, 20150324, 20150325],
    type: 'sick'
  }],
  year: '2016'
}, {
  loginName: 'chloe',
  deviation: [{
    dates: [20150222, 20150221, 20150224, 20150225],
    type: 'national free day'
  }],
  year: '2016'
}];

var o = {}
var result = data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (!o[e.loginName]) {
    o[e.loginName] = e;
    r.push(o[e.loginName]);
  } else {
    o[e.loginName].deviation[0].dates.push(...e.deviation[0].dates)
    o[e.loginName].deviation[0].type += ' ' + e.deviation[0].type
    o[e.loginName].year += ' ' + e.year
  }
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I tried your method and in the browser it works great and outputs the wanted results. But I get my userName array dinamically from client and when I generate the document with your function, it prints out a blank page. As I said I get no errors in the console. Any idea why that may be?

Comment: Its hard to say without knowing your code. Could you make a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: I doubt it, I use placeholders for the key values and I can only make the code work on our webclient, whick recognises those placeholders.

Comment: thanks though for the code. I am interested in learning more about the 'reduce()' function and how to use it. Can you recommend me some sites with examples or exercises?

Comment: You can start here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce